# Detect Phone Vendor at installation

Tags: android

I am developing device specific application, Can anybody knows how to detect android phone vendor i.e `samsung` or `htc` etc in `android` ... Is this possible?.
That according to phone vendor i can decide to install application on that phone or not !!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use below code to get phone vendor

```
String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

It will return name of vendor. For example `Samsung` if it is a samsung phone.

I think detecting is not possible at installation time but you can detect this in your first activity screen like splash screen if manufacturer name is same then you run the application and if vendor is different you can show error screen with message that this app run only on phones of specified vendor.

Comment: I have "samsung" not "Samsung" as the Manufacturer (S3 Model SAMSUNG-SGH-I747)